# CloudDeploy DataSet does not work

Tags: bugs, dataset, cloud-deploy, apifunction

I'm getting the following error when the code bellow is CloudDeployed:

```
Dataset[Null[<|"title" -> "Posts"["Title"], "comments_count" -> "Posts"["CommentsCount"], "ups" -> "Posts"["Ups"], "awards" -> 1, "award_total_price" -> Total["Posts"["all_awardings"["coin_price"]]], "creation_date" -> "Posts"["CreationDate"]|>], TypeSystem`AnyType, <||>]
```

[image]

#### What I did to debug?

`GetPosts[1]` runs fine on local and when I pass it directly into `APIFunction` without using dynamic variables it works. However, when I pass is a dynamic variable I'm getting the error from above. It's as if the version running in the cloud is not the same as the one running on local.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Wolfram support and got the following answer.

> I have forwarded an issue report to our Cloud development team. We hope this can be resolved in the future versions of Wolfram Cloud.

So that is not working in `Wolfram 12.2.0.0`.

Comment: What if you try to ServiceConnect manually in the APIFunction with explicitly provided credentials?